# Create Formatter object fails

Tags: java, android, locale

I have following simple code snippet:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Locale l = Locale.getDefault();         
Formatter formatter = new Formatter( sb, l );
```

In documentation I see that the **Formatter** has following constructor:

```
Formatter(Appendable a, Locale l)
```

So why the compiler tells me there is an error in my code:

> *The constructor
>   Formatter(StringBuilder, Locale) is
>   undefined*

Sorry for such simple questions...

BR

STeN

---

*Answer (added later): I was by mistake using the **android.text.format.Formatter**, which was automatically imported by Eclipse instead of **java.util.Formatter**.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code works for me. Do you have an import problem? There are three Formatter classes in Android: java.util, android.text.formatting, and android.util.logging.